# c# property incrementer method

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, emit

I am creating a dynamic type at runtime with the purpose of creating/serializing/deserializing objects from this type to then bind to a grid control.  Everything works but my way of updating properties with records from the database is pathetic.  I pasted this setter generator from somewhere and it works wonderfully when called via either delegate or PropertyInfo(...).SetValue(...)

```
ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
```

But when I try to get cheeky and make my own version that increments rather than setting

```
ILGenerator incIl = incMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //add object to stack
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder); //add current field value to stack
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); //add method parameter to stack
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Add);    //combine last 2 items
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); //write added value back
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);    //no clue
incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

When I try to invoke this bad boy either via a delegate or even GetMethod(...).Invoke(...) I get the same fail

```
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

Pretty obvious my il is wrong but I am not seeing the exact issue.  I wouldn't even mind modifying the setter as the only thing that's ever done to these properties is that they're incremented

Also thanks in advance to anyone who comments that my design is bad

Comment: Can you talk us through why you think you need a dynamic type at runtime? _Just in case this is a XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem_

Comment: `OpCodes.Stfld` need reference to object to store non-static field, but you consume one with `OpCodes.Ldfld`.

Comment: As you can see from the first piece of code, `stfld` has two operands. Only one is left on the stack in your code. You need an extra `ldarg.0`.

Comment: Just a note that may help you: try writing your code in c#/vb and then view the IL generated either by using the appropriate tools in visual studio or with a decompiler/ildasm. You can then replicate the necessary IL in your dynamic type.

Comment: If you have a complete answer don't just write it in comments. Put it in that lovely answer box. Comments are great for requesting clarifications or even just suggesting things for the OP to think about but when you are telling them how to fix thins the answer box is the place for that, not the comment box.

Comment: @mjwills users can customize the report templates so a static type isn't going to cut it.  The reports are calculated offsite sometimes and are then transferred via sockets.  I realize this could mostly be done via datatables but they are massive when serialized and in many cases the serialization fails.  Also it's not a dynamic type at runtime every time, the types are serialized then re-used until some modification to the template is made. As we are talking massive datasets I am trying to get optimal performance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.  All but the XY arrogance were helpful.  The comment about ildasm being the most helpful.  I had forgotten about this but it's fantastic. Nearly gave me an ildasm.

```
MethodBuilder incPropMthdBldr =
            tb.DefineMethod("_Inc" + propertyName,
              MethodAttributes.Public ,
              null, new[] { propertyType });
        incPropMthdBldr.DefineParameter(0, ParameterAttributes.In, "increaseBy");
        ILGenerator incIl = incPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);            
        incIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The best results invoking were done by following this guide https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10951/WebControls/ One of the comments is copy/paste gold. I am caching the delegates

```
private Dictionary<Int32, DynamicMethodDelegate> valueDeltas;
```

then as my transform block hits the checkered flag

```
foreach (var kvp in result)
        {               
            valueDeltas[kvp.Key](rowData, kvp.Value[0]);
            sampleDeltas[kvp.Key](rowData, kvp.Value[1]); //...
```

the overall my approach is still nowhere near 100% efficient it is massively improved over datatables